# How to change Java version on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, java

I have done the following:

**1. Set the environment variable JAVA_HOME:**
[image]

**2. Add Java 1.6.0_45 and disable Java 1.8.0_66 in Java Runtime Environment Settings under Configure Java:**
[image]

Unfortunately, the Java is still 1.8.0_66:

```
>java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b18, mixed mode)
```

Could anyone offer a tip on this?

**Edit:**

Per David's suggestion, the following is the Java related contents from the output of command PATH (the entire output is super long, I hope the following is sufficient for this question.):

```
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath; ... C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin
```

Comment: Please [edit] and include the output of `path` in a `cmd` shell.

Comment: @DavidPostill  I have just done it following your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` will be `1.8.0_66`. Put `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin` first.

Comment: Note that changes to environment variables may not be fully applied until you sign in again. Reboot and try `java -version` again.

Comment: @DavidPostill I noticed that after checking the path per your suggestion.    Windows 10 does not allow me to edit the path because it says "This environment variable is too large."  I know there should be another question to deal with this separately.

Comment: Have you tried to put just ´%JAVA_HOME%\bin´ instead ´C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin´

Comment: @Hong "This environment variable is too large" - you need to clean up your path. My guess is you have a lot of dupe entries.

Comment: @DavidPostill  I managed to delete "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" and put "%JAVA_HOME%\bin" first.  Now Java -version returns "1.6.0_45".  The PATH command returns "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;" as the first.   Could you turn your comment to an Answer so that I can accept and close this question?

Comment: @Stackcraft_noob ´C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin´ was actually the result of  ´%JAVA_HOME%\bin´ that I added to the user (not system) variable PATH.  Now I have moved it to the system PATH.

Comment: @gronostaj I have noticed that I need to restart CMD, not the computer, after changing the environment.

Comment: @Stackcraft_noob thanks for the tip, for me, the windows didn't want to recognize the ´C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin´, but did accept ´%JAVA_HOME%\bin´

Comment: I would remove javapath from PATH and add the actual java version directory directly. This allows easy switching without the need to maintain the registry. Note that this is not true for in-Browser Java.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### `java -version` is running the wrong version of java.

**Diagnostics:**

```
>java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b18, mixed mode)
```

> the following is the Java related contents from the output of `PATH`:

```
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath; ... C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin
```

**Conclusion:**

From the above output we can deduce that `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` is `1.8.0_66`.

You need to change your `PATH` to put `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin` first.

> I noticed that after checking the path per your suggestion. Windows 10 does not allow me to edit the path because it says "This environment variable is too large." I know there should be another question to deal with this separately.

You also need to clean up your path. My guess is you have a lot of duplicate entries.

Comment: Order changing doesn't help, `java -version` is always 8. My configuration: Windows 10 with jdk 8 installed alongside jdk 7.

Comment: @naXa Please ask your own question, supplying the appropriate information.

Answer (score 16):

I have the same problem, I have set `JAVA_HOME`:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75
```

and `Path` to:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

I need run jdk 7. When I run `java -version` it always appear jdk 8.

I solved it with:  in System Environment --> Path --> order `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to first.

Comment: This answer is correct

Comment: This is the correct answer !! Thank you very much !!

Comment: I had to restart my computer before it worked.

Comment: After hours of experimenting with the environment variables and the java config settings in VS Code, this finally made it clear what actually determined which version of java was running... thank you

Answer (score 5):

This is the REAL active JAVA executable into your PATH:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
```

Remove it and the system take the value from

```
...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin\;
```

Comment: No, it's not a "REAL" java! It's the oracle's way to redirect the "java.exe", etc. simple executions to the "REAL" java installation, which is specified in 
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment

So this solution is replacing the registry-based indirection (managed by java installers) with the Environment-variable based indirection (managed by theuser).

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51457823/849897

Answer (score 2):

[image]

As you can check the javapath variable under system's environment path variable.

So if you want to use your own version.You can do

- 1) Create new variable in systems variable
- 2) Name it as JAVA_HOME and give jdk installation path
- 3) add this variable in path and move it to top.
- 4) check java -version

you need to create a JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 2):

Check also registry. Press Win key-R, type `regedit`. Search for `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment`. If there is something different, than you expect, than it is better to reinstall Java. If it not possible, very carefully change the settings. Be aware, that from version to version the setup can be different. In my case I would to downgrade from Java 1.9 to 1.8.

[Java Registry Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FOLe.png)

Answer (score 1):

I just uninstalled Java6 that resides in c:Windows\System32 like a noxious weed.  Problem gone.

Comment: With old java installers a java.exe is often present in `c:\Windows\System32` the classic headache!

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the other recommendations, I *still* found Windows 10 to be running the wrong version of Java.  The correct version of Java ran in a command shell, but Windows would not start an application with the correct version of Java.

In my system, there was yet another entry in the Registry.  So, I opened the registry editor, and changed `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\open\command` to point to the correct version.

This finally fixed the problem I was having.